# Shorthand for querying a table in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Say I have a model named `User`, and a tabled called `followers`:

```
followers = db.Table(
    'followers',
    db.Column('follower_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('followed_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    followed = db.relationship(
        'User',
        secondary=followers,
        primaryjoin=(followers.c.follower_id==id),
        secondaryjoin=(followers.c.followed_id==id),
        backref=db.backref('followers', lazy='dynamic'),
        lazy='dynamic'
    )
```

There are two ways to query the `User` model:

1. `db.session.query(User).filter(...).all()`
2. `User.query.filter(...).all()`

The latter is considered a shorthand for the former, because they are functionally identical but it's more compact. However, when comes to the table,`followers.query.filter(...).all()` gives me an error:

> AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'query'

Is there a shorthand for `db.session.query(followers).filter(...).all()`? or, how can I get a `query` object from a `table` object?

Answer (score 1):

There might be an issue with your Follower object you might wanna check it out again.

Follower.query.all() should work

If you happen to have have a relationship in your User with followers such as.

```
class User():
    followers = db.relationship("Followers", lazy='dynamic')
```

You can execute via:

```
user = User.query.get(id=1)
user.followers.all()
```

*Updated

The declaration of your followers table is not equivalent to how you declared the User table. User table is base on the db.Model and db.Model has a query class attached to it:
http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/api/#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.Model

Also you can check out the road to enlightenment part at the bottom of the page.

http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/quickstart/#quickstart

Comment: In my question, `followers` isn't a field of the model `User`, it's a separate *table*.

Comment: Kindly post your follower and user schema or table definition

Comment: Definition posted.

Comment: Ok, after posting it has something to do with how you declared the followers table. I have updated the answer for you. The followers table isn't a class of db.Model that's why you can't execute a query class.

Answer (score 1):

flask-sqlalchemy defines `query` only on `db.Model`, so while you can do `Foo.query` on anything that subclasses `db.Model`, you cannot do the same on `Table` instances.

You could monkeypatch that in, I suppose, but I would not recommend doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @univerio answer: Instead monkey-patching you could wrap the `flask_sqlalchemy.Table` into your custom class, which would include the `query` property as shorthand.

```
class QueryableTable:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        table = db.Table(*args, **kwargs)
        super().__setattr__('_flask_sa_table', table)

    @property
    def query(self):
        return db.session.query(self._flask_sa_table)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.__dict__['_flask_sa_table'], name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        return setattr(self._flask_sa_table, name, value)
```

Use it as `followers = QueryableTable('followers', db.Column(...), ...)`

Answer (score 0):

To use `session.query()` method to retrieve the rows from the table, you have to put the table name inside the `query()`.

For example: For table name "fellowers", put `session.query(fellowers).filter_by(id = fellow_id).one()`

Comment: yes that's true, but my question is about a **shorthand** for `session.query(fellowers).filter_by(id = fellow_id).one()`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how conventional is the solution that I used, but I took `pandas.read_sql_query` ([link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html#pandas.read_sql_query)) so it works more or less that way:

```
pandas.read_sql_query('SELECT your_table_column from followers WHERE follower_id = your_id', your_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])
```

That gives me all records which are related to required follower_id as a pandas dataframe, which is possible to process further.